# How to fit JTextArea as my file require?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I want my JTextArea to show text as in the txt file. But it is showing the whole text in only row.

http://pastebin.com/Y8vWUvtg

```
package jBoxThreadTry;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GuestFinal extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private JLabel test;
    private JTextArea txtArea;
    private String titleBar;
    private static String fileName;

    private String[] CSEterms = {"CSE11.txt", "CSE12.txt", "CSE21.txt",
        "CSE22.txt", "CSE31.txt", "CSE32.txt", "CSE41.txt", "CSE42.txt"};

    private boolean threadAliveFlag;

    public GuestFinal(boolean threadAliveFlag) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        // super()
        this.threadAliveFlag = threadAliveFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while (threadAliveFlag) {
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                setVisible(true);
                setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                /*test = new JLabel("yes");
                 add(test);
                 */
                setTitle(titleBar);

                threadAliveFlag = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public void setBool(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        threadAliveFlag = b;
    }

    public void setTitleBar(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        titleBar = "Syllabus for " + string;
    }

    public void setFileToShow(int selectedIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fileName = CSEterms[selectedIndex];
        showFile(fileName);
    }

    private void showFile(String fName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("syllabusDir\\"
                    + fName);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            String line = br.readLine();
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while (line != null) {
                // Print the content on the console
                System.out.println(line);
                strBuilder.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            String everything = strBuilder.toString();

            txtArea = new JTextArea(everything);
            add(txtArea);

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code here not on an external site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I want my JTextArea to show text as in the txt file. But it is showing the whole text in only row"

```
while (line != null) {
     // Print the content on the console
     System.out.println(line);
     strBuilder.append(line);
     line = br.readLine();
}
```

A string is just a long sequence of character. So what you are doing is just appending to the same sequence of characters. The way to separate lines is to make use of the line separator `\n` character. So you want to append that after every line.

```
strBuilder.append(line);
strBuilder.append("\n");
```

Alternativelive, not much of a difference in this case, but `JTextArea` also has an `append` method.

---

**UPDATE**

The most resonable approach is to just use the [`JTextArea.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method, which you can pass the `BufferedReader` to, and that will read the whole file the text area. No need to loop and append.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10, 50);
area.read(reader, null);
```

Simple as that

Comment: +1 for using the read() method and NOT reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
What if I want to add a slider?
Here is an example of my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1zwffgns7vw7ip/CSE11.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Dipto_Das `JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(textArea);`. Then add the scroll pane to the frame. Make sure you *don't* also add the text area to the frame too

Comment: @Dipto_Das And make sure to create you text area like `new JTextArea(rows, columns)`

Answer (score 1):

This block of code:

```
while (line != null) {
     // Print the content on the console
     System.out.println(line);
     strBuilder.append(line);
     line = br.readLine();
}
```

change `strBuilder.append(line);` to `strBuilder.append(line+"\n");`

Append will not add the newline as you are intending here.

Also, use `txtArea.setLineWrap(true);` to ensure lines will always be wrapped if you are looking for that functionality.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Yes, it may fix the problem but it is a waste of memory to first read the data into a StringBuilder and then add the String to the JTextArea. If you use this approach, then just use the `append(...)` method every time you read a line. Or, the better solution is to use the `read(...)` method so you don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a convenient way to read files using streams and NIO

```
 public String readFile(String fName) throws IOException {
    List<String> contents = Files.readAllLines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("syllabusDir\\"
            + fName));
    return contents
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Also see `java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.charset.Charset)`